# CCBill integration with magento

Tags: magento

Can anyone give the steps to work with ccbill integration in magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look didn't return any results on existing extensions for this, so you'll need to write your own payment method code. The Magento site has a [nice tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) on this.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

There's finally a CCBill extension for Magento.  Hope it helps.  http://plugindistrict.com/shop/magento/ccbill-payment-gateway-magento/